# Getting wrong values for other columns when I select MAX(updated_date)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, rdbms, max

I am using `select field1, max(updated_date) from mytable`.
I get the correct value for `max(updated_date)`, i.e. the largest date.
However for `field1` I just get the the value for the first record, i.e. "ta1" when I really want the "ta3" value from the third record (the one with the max date value).

e.g.

```
+------------+---------------------+
| field1     | update_date         |
+------------+---------------------+
| ta1        | 2012-03-11 11:05:15 |
| ta2        | 2012-03-11 11:05:32 |
| ta3        | 2012-03-11 11:05:56 |
+------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+------------+---------------------+
| field1     | max(update_date)    |
+------------+---------------------+
| ta1        | 2012-03-11 11:05:56 |
+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire SQL query?

Comment: That's it nb. there is no where clause.

Comment: Not sure how mysql works aggregate functions, but in SQL Server you would get a syntax error for leaving out the group by clause.

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that if two or more records share the same `MAX` date, you will either receive multiple records (as in Jonathan Leffler's answer) or you may not get the same result on each run (as in Adam Bernier's answer). You will need to sort by an additional field to break ties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either need a GROUP BY clause or a more complex query.

```
SELECT field1, MAX(updated_date)
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY field1
```

For the sample data, this will return 3 rows.

More likely, you want:

```
SELECT t1.field1, t3.max_date
  FROM mytable AS t1
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(t2.updated_date) AS max_date
          FROM mytable AS t2
       ) AS t3
    ON t1.updated_date = t3.max_date;
```

For the sample data, this will return 1 row:

```
ta3   2012-03-11 11:05:56
```

Of the major DBMS, only MySQL allows you to omit the GROUP BY clause when you have a mixture of aggregates and non-aggregate columns in the select-list.  The SQL standard requires the GROUP BY clause and you must list all non-aggregate columns in it.  Sometimes, in MySQL, omitting the GROUP BY clause produces the answer you want; as often as not, though, it manages to give an unexpected answer.

Comment: Actually, in PostgreSQL 9.1 (or later) a primary key column(s) listed in the GROUP BY clause covers all columns of that table. You don't need to spell out all columns used in the SELECT list any more. (You cannot aggregate them either, of course.)

Comment: So PostgreSQL is aware of keys, which is good, but it still requires the PK to be listed in the GROUP BY clause ... so only MySQL allows you to omit the GROUP BY clause altogether.  I like PostgreSQL's extension; I've yet to be convinced by MySQL's.

Comment: I absolutely agree. The PostgreSQL feature is a syntactical convenience, the MySQL "feature" is a loaded footgun.

Answer (score 3):

Use ORDER BY and LIMIT.
Then it's as simple as:

```
  SELECT field1, updated_date 
    FROM mytable
ORDER BY updated_date DESC 
   LIMIT 1;
```

---

If the query is needed a lot you can try this alternative:

```
  SELECT t1.field1, t1.updated_date 
    FROM mytable t1
         LEFT JOIN mytable t2 
     AND t2.updated_date > t1.updated_date
   WHERE t2.field1 IS NULL;
```

Short explanation:
For each row, give me any rows with a more-recent `updated_date`.
But (WHERE clause) take only the row with no more-recent `updated_date`.
The technique is sometimes called a self-exclusion join.
This is the intermediate result (without WHERE clause, and adding `t2.*` to SELECT list):

```
ta1    2012-03-11 11:05:15    ta2     2012-03-11 11:05:32
ta1    2012-03-11 11:05:15    ta3     2012-03-11 11:05:56
ta2    2012-03-11 11:05:32    ta3     2012-03-11 11:05:56
ta3    2012-03-11 11:05:56    null    null
```