# MySQL: Selecting all rows with the same name, then updating another column for all except the higest value?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem which I'm having trouble putting the pieces together for.

The table in question houses online highscores for a game, and the in-game highscore list is getting saturated with the same name over and over again as people have aimed higher. What I'd like to do is only keep one score per name such that more users can see their name in the top scores (or rather, multiply all their scores except their highest by -1, so I keep the data but the negative scores won't be loaded).

The flow would be:

1. Select all of the same name from names column
2. Update where highscore is not the largest value in the first selection by multiplying score by -1.
3. Repeat for all different names.

The key problems I haven't found solutions for are selecting the names one by one without the need to type each name in, and then updating all but their top score within the selection.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
TFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table looks like:

```
------------------------------------
| player_name |    date    | score |
------------------------------------
| Max         | 01-03-2015 |  100  |
| Daniel      | 27-02-2015 |  150  |
| Max         | 24-02-2015 |  200  |
| Daniel      | 26-02-2015 |  100  |
------------------------------------
```

You can do a `SELECT` statement with an `ANY` predicate containing a `GROUP BY` to get the highest score for each group, which in this case is the player, along with the date of that score.

```
SELECT 
  player_name, date, score AS "max_score"
FROM 
  highscores t1
WHERE
  (t1.player_name, t1.score) = ANY(SELECT t2.player_name, max(t2.score) FROM highscores t2 GROUP BY t2.player_name);
```

This should give you the following result:

```
----------------------------------------
| player_name |    date    | max_score |
----------------------------------------
| Daniel      | 27-02-2015 |    150    |
| Max         | 24-02-2015 |    200    |
----------------------------------------
```

Note that if you just wanted to get the player_name and MAX(score), you could have used the simple `GROUP BY` subquery contained inside the `ANY` expression.  However, since you also need the date, this won't work as SQL has no way of knowing **which** date from the group to include.  According to the SQL standard, the SELECT may contain only columns mentioned in the `GROUP BY` (player_name) or expressions based on aggregate functions.  Hence the you cannot include the date in a simple `GROUP BY` query and hope to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It almost worked exactly how I had tried to explain- I hadn't realised the GROUP BY function would mean I wouldn't actually have to change the values in the database. The code which worked is this:                                                                                                

SELECT player_name, MAX(score) FROM highscores GROUP BY player_name ORDER BY score DESC

Comment: I've encountered a slight issue: I also have a date column, and now the first date the player_name registered a score is always showing up as opposed to the date the score was achieved. Is there a way to make it choose the date that is associated with the value of MAX(score)? This is the current statement: SELECT player_name , date, MAX(score) FROM highscores GROUP BY player_name ORDER BY `MAX(score)`......Edit: I think this is a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657695/getting-wrong-values-for-other-columns-when-i-select-maxupdated-date