# How do I write a LINQ query for a list of users with their first article?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, linq2db

How do I write a LINQ query that would translate to the following SQL?

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.username, a.id, MIN(a.created_at) AS firstArticle
FROM users u
INNER JOIN editorial_articles a
ON a.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id, a.created_at, a.id
```

Basically, a list of users with their first article.

Everything that I try results in an incorrect group-by clause (too many columns), not enough columns selected, or some other issue.

I've tried a thousand different combinations – why is this so difficult?

Classes:

```cs
[Table("users")]
public class User
{
    [Column("id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsIdentity = true, SkipOnInsert = true, SkipOnUpdate = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; } // int

    [Column("username", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!; // varchar(20)

    [Association(ThisKey = nameof(Id), OtherKey = nameof(Article.UserId))]
    public IEnumerable<Article> Articles { get; set; } = null!;
}

[Table("articles")]
public class Article
{
    [Column("id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsIdentity = true, SkipOnInsert = true, SkipOnUpdate = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; } // int
    
    [Column("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; } // int
    
    [Column("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } // datetime

    [Association(CanBeNull = false, ThisKey = nameof(UserId), OtherKey = nameof(User.Id))]
    public User User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

**Update:**

The closest that I get with a GROUP BY is:

```cs
var result =
    from user in db.Users
    join article in db.Articles
    on user.Id equals article.UserId into articles
    from article in articles
    group article by new { user } into g
    orderby g.Key.user.Id, g.Min(a => a.CreatedAt), g.Min(a => a.Id)
    select new
    {
        User = g.Key,
        FirstArticle = g.Min(a => a.CreatedAt)
    };
```

I don't like that it puts all of the user fields into the group-by. If you just group by `Id`, then it's not possible to reference the initial `user` in the select.

Is there no way to group by ID, but select additional fields?

Comment: Ca;you add your class structures to your question and show an example of what you have tried?

Comment: I think I understand why this happens now – if you only group by `user.Id`, but select `user.Username` as well, and there are two or more users with the same ID but different usernames (not the case, but LINQ doesn't know), then it can't know which of the usernames to select, and the key is therefore not unique. It can work at the SQL level though, since there is only one username per user ID.

Comment: This query uses MySQL quirk that filed which is not used in grouping key can be retrieved from result. It is not ANSI stadard and you cannot generate such query via `linq2db` .

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yep, I finally understand that now. Apparently with PostgreSQL, you only need to include the PK (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657695/getting-wrong-values-for-other-columns-when-i-select-maxupdated-date#comment12264846_9657773).

Comment: I cannot understand how PK can help here. Postgres supports LATERAL JOIN (CROSS APPLY) and this query can be rewritten without Window function. Other solutions are workaround.

Comment: It's just interesting that PostgreSQL doesn't require you to list all of the columns, I'm not suggesting that GROUP BY is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Window Function `ROW_NUMBER` for such task:

```cs
var query = 
    from u in db.Users
    from a in u.Articles
    select new
    {
        User = u,
        FirstArticle = a,
        RN = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over()
            .PartitionBy(u.Id)
            .OrderBy(a.CreatedAt)
            .ToValue()
    } into s
    where s.RN == 1
    select new 
    {
        s.User,
        s.FirstArticle
    };
```

Comment: "Database do not support CROSS/OUTER APPLY join required by the query" (I'm using MySqlConnector)

Comment: @glen-84, corrected answer for your database engine.

Comment: I think `.OrderBy(a => a.CreatedAt)` should be `.OrderBy(a.CreatedAt)`?

Comment: You are right. My fault.

Comment: I think it might work (thanks), but it seems overly complex – is there no way to replicate the simple group-by? I've posted an update to my initial question, that shows progress, but I only want to group by ID, and not the entire object, and then select a few other fields without them being included in the group-by.

Comment: Yes, i can write the same query as you requested, but with GroupBy it is less effective query. `ROW_NUMBER` fits here perfectly.

Comment: I'm still very curious to know what it would look like, even if I do decide to go with your `ROW_NUMBER` solution. 

Comment: You want to get User with it's First article - ROW_NUMBER is the fastest way. GroupBy is a workaround.

Comment: I believe you, but I'm curious to see what the code would look like, regardless of performance.